# Is it possible to create this kind of chart with any of the Drupal charts modules?

Tags: drupal, charts, google-visualization

I am trying to figure out how can I create a chart similar to this one:

[image]

Such chart is to be created with any of the available Drupal modules for creating charts.

I am used to using the [chart](http://drupal.org/project/chart) module, but I don't know how to implement this kind of charts with it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Examples](http://code.google.com/p/drupal-chart-api/wiki/Examples) link, I think you should definitely be able to do it.  If you still can't figure it out after reading that then let me know, and I can see where you are at.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to do it using [Google chart tools module](http://drupal.org/project/google_chart_tools). I truly like this module more because it allows building interactive charts. My code can be found below:

```
function test_chart() {
  $settings = array();


  $settings['chart']['chartOne'] = array(  
    'header' => array('2004', '2005', '2006'),
    'rows' => array(array('100', '500', '300') , array('900', '800','200')),
    'columns' => array('Sales', 'Expenses'),
    'chartType' => 'BarChart',
    'containerId' =>  'org_chart',
    'options' => array( 
      'forceIFrame' => FALSE, 
      'title' => 'Bar Chart Test',
      'width' => 550,
      'height' => 250,
      'vAxis' => array(title => 'Year',titleTextStyle=>array(color=>'red'))
    )   
  );
  //Draw it.
  draw_chart($settings); 
  return '<p>Example org chart:</p><div id="org_chart" class="org_chart"></div>';

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware that the answer with the examples link (for the  [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module) is no longer the recommended URL for finding the documentation about this module. While I'm at it, I add some related info here ...

There are indeed a lot of [charts related modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) these days that can be used for creating charts in Drupal.

The [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) module's project page contains some information that indicates it is "being depreciated and users are recommended to move over to the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module". Though most recently some comments in the chart issue queue contain some details that illustrate that that depreciation is being reconsidered. Refer to that issue queue for more details on that.

If needed, do not hesitate to create an issue in the module's issue queue. As an alternative create a new question on this site (or Drupal Answers) and find a way to let me know about it (eg via some comment in any of my questions or answers around here).

**Be aware**: I'm the maintainer of both modules [Chart](https://www.drupal.org/project/chart) and [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts), and the author of the documentation of [Comparison of charting modules](https://www.drupal.org/node/2363985) mentioned in the beginning of my answer also.